# Need help configuring WordPress on Ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

I am trying to install WordPress on my Ubuntu server. I have tried these tutorials:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview
http://lubuntuhowto.blogspot.com/2017/05/how-to-install-wordpress-on-lubuntu-1604.html

- I have installed WP
- I updated the configuration file as seen below

  ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin user@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        <Directory /var/www/mysite>
             Options FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
             DirectoryIndex index.php
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/mysite/wp-content>
             Options FollowSymLinks
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

   </VirtualHost>
  ```
- I configured the DB
- I created the /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php

  ```
  <?php
  define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
  define('DB_USER', 'user');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pswd');
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/usr/share/wordpress/wp-content');
  ?>
  ```
- I created the symbolic link

  ```
  sudo ln -s /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php /etc/wordpress/config-default.php
  ```
- I enabled the configuration and
- I restarted the apache service

I have another site running. This is my hosts file with mySite

```
   127.0.0.1 ubuntu
   127.0.0.1 localhost
   111.111.111.111 anotherSite.com
   111.111.111.111 mysite.com
```

And since I am trying to access mySite from my Windows machine I updated the hosts file as follows:

```
   192.168.1.20 anotherSite.com
   192.168.1.20 mySite.com
```

I honestly did not expect it to work because there is absolutely nothing inside /var/www/mysite, and after doing all this I don't see how the machine can link WP to this directory. Shouldn't there be WP content here?

When I go to mySite.com on Windows I get a

```
   Forbidden
   You don't have permission to access this resource.
   Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at pep.com Port 80
```

I am out of ideas and gone through enough tutorials without finding a solution.
I hope you guys can help.
TY

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Directory' replace "Allow from all" with "Require all granted",
[Apache vhost config changed in 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html)

Comment: TY - It did not seem to work. I did not have to run any commands after, right?

Comment: Did you restart Apache?